# German equivalent of “I pulled a [name]”

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

There are two related English idioms

> I went full [name] on her/him.
>
> I pulled a [name].

as in:

> I pulled a Clinton.
>
> She went full Lewinsky on me.

This means that you did something similar to what the person in question was famous for, e.g. (from [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pulling+a+Cinderella)):

> *pulling a Cinderella* – When you have a crush on someone and you intentionally leave a personal belonging in that person’s car, house, etc. so that they will eventually call you or come see you to give your stuff back, thus getting to see him/her again.

How do you translate those into proper German?

Comment: What have you come up with so far? What is still unclear? Note that this is not a translation service and posts asking for translations without showing any work of your own are likely to be closed soon.

Comment: What is "pulling a Clinton" or "went full X on her" coming from, in English? Sounds as if "pulling a trump card" could be the origin, or maybe a Joker.

Comment: @userunknown I do not know. What would "pulling a trump card" be in german?

Comment: Interesting phrase to try to translate. I don't think that it is in any way related to playing a trump card (*Einen Trumpf (aus)spielen*), as it means something like *acting like the person in question, in a stereotypical way*. E.g. *She went full Lewinsky on me* - service someone (especially their boss) orally. Finding a good translation for this will not fit into a comment, especially as it is colloquial speech which doesn't necessarily have a corresponding translation.

Comment: @Chieron Vieleicht "Sie zeigte mir ihre innere Lewinsky..." oder "da brach die Lewinsky aus ihr raus". Eher schlecht "Ich handelte wie Clinton", besser "Ich habe meinen inneren Clinton freigelassen".

Comment: @VitalisHommel *da ist die Lewinsky mit ihr durchgegangen*.. Problem bei solchen Konstruktionen ist, dass dies eher unwillkürliche Handlungen beschreibt. Passt also nicht in allen Situationen. Ich weiß jetzt aber auch keine gute Alternative, weshalb ich die Frage lieber wiedereröffnen würde.

Comment: I don't see any sensible reason to close this question.  "to pull sth. off  on someone" is an idiom. (And those people too lazy to google an English idiom – whilst being users of an international, English-language site, no less – should lose their right to vote for holding/closing questions, to be honest.)

Comment: @Chieron: Eine Trumpfkarte ziehen hat immerhin was von Ziehen. Wo sonst wird etwas gezogen, was hier Pate gestanden haben kann? Im dt. gibt es etwas ähnliches mit "den sterbenden Schwan geben" oder "mach mir den Elch", Begriffe die auf Schauspiel/Theater hinweisen.

Comment: Ich glaube es gibt kein gutes Analogon. "Einen auf Levinski machen" wäre eine Approximation.

Comment: @userunknown Kartenziehen im Englischen ist *draw a card*, nicht *pull*. Außerdem ist eignet sich das Ziehen ohnehin nicht, da die Karte metaphorisch immer noch verdeckt ist. (Zumal afaik kein bedeutenderes Spiel mit Trümpfen Kartenziehen als wichtige Mechanik beinhaltet).  Die Theaterbeispiele sind deutlich passendere Analogien.

Comment: You could also [modify the name to make it sound like a verb](http://www.spiegel.de/sport/fussball/superstar-ibrahimovic-zlatanieren-in-duden-aufgenommen-a-874864.html)

Answer (score 7):

I have two suggestions:

- > Ich machte den/die [Name] (mit ihm/ihr).

  for example:

  > Ich machte die Clinton.

  To give a specific example: *Den [Guttenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl-Theodor_zu_Guttenberg) machen* would either be plagiarising something or admitting to errors only peu à peu (see [Guttenplag](http://de.guttenplag.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:%22Guttenberg_machen%22_-_pro_Duden-Eintrag) for an extensive discussion).
- Plainly turning the name into a verb:

  > Ich habe ihn/sie/es ge[name]t.

  for example:

  > Ich habe ihn getrumpt.

  This works much better with some names than with others, as not all names are equally verbable. I cannot pinpoint exact criteria, but names ending on a vowel (Lewinsky) or a reduced syllable (Clinton) do not work well (hence Trump as an example).

  To give a specific example, *[wulff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Wulff)en* would be either to sputter (threats or insults) on an answering machine or trying to save one’s head by walking a fine line between truth and lie that is certainly not the truth but also not an sufficiently explicit lie that would cost one one’s head (see [Spiegel Online](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/gesellschaft/spott-ueber-bundespraesidenten-neues-verb-wulffen-entstanden-a-808568.html) for an extensive discussion).

Comment: Als Ergänzung: "Ich mache einen auf Clinton/Gutenberg/Trump" ginge auch.

Comment: Für die Verbneuschöpfung: Ich denke, *lewinskieren* ginge auch noch (bei solchen Schöpfungen ist es nur notwendig, dass das Ausgangswort und die Wortart erkennbar sind). *clinten* wäre aber tatsächlich schwierig.

Comment: "Den [...] geben" ist nicht exakt äquivalent, kann aber auch verwendet werden.

Answer (score -2):

> She went full Lewinsky on me.

=>

> Sie behandelte mich so, wie Lewinsky es tun würde.

Comment: Grammatikalisch ist das korrekt, aber das sagt doch so keiner.

Comment: @Iris "Ich mache einen auf Clinton/Gutenberg/Trump" ist besser als meine Idee, meine geht aber auch. Dein/Ludis Vorschlag nimmt das Umgangssprachliche besser mit, meines ist förmlicher...

Comment: in einem förmlichen Kontext, würde man meiner Meinung nach erst gar nicht über Blowjobs mit Praktikantinnen (etwas anderes ist "She went full Lewinsky on me") reden....

Comment: @Iris Dein Einwand ist falsch, weil du Lewinsky auch durch eine andere Person ersetzen kannst.